# Convert revenue figues in European format to American using Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, format, locale

I am having a dataframe where revenue figures are in German format with `€` like

```
print(df['Revenue'])
0       23.979,12 €
1    7.993.137,63 €
2          418,83 €
Name: Revenue, dtype: object
```

Is there a way of converting it into

```
print(df['Revenue'])
0       23979.12
1    7993137.63
2          418.83
Name: Revenue, dtype: float
```

It can be done using replace function by first converting these strings in right format using the code `df.replace({'€':'', '\.':'',',':'.'}, regex=True,inplace=True)`, and then converting string into float. The only problem with this issue is that it's too slow.

I have read that it can be done using LOCALEs, but not sure. I am sure Python/Pandas has a better way to dealing with these. Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assumption here is that `df['Revenue']` is a string column. This should do:

```
df    
         Revenue
0     23.979,12 €
1  7.993.137,63 €
2        418,83 €

df['Revenue'] = df['Revenue'].str.replace('[^\d,]', '')\
                  .str.replace(',', '.', regex=False).astype(float)
df
      Revenue
0    23979.12
1  7993137.63
2      418.83

df.Revenue.dtypes
dtype('float64')
```

Anything that is not a digit or comma is removed. The next call will convert the commas to decimal points (I've switched off the regex engine for this one since it isn't necessary), and a final `astype` call wraps it up.

**Regex**

```
[     # character class
^     # negation - ignore anything inside this char group
\d    # digit
,     # comma
]
```

---

piR has a [great suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465641/is-there-a-way-to-convert-revenue-figues-in-german-european-format-to-american-f/46465704?noredirect=1#comment79886739_46465704). If your data can guarantee me two decimal places always, I can simplify your solution to:

```
df['Revenue'] = df['Revenue'].str.replace('[^\d]', '').astype(float) / 100
df
      Revenue
0    23979.12
1  7993137.63
2      418.83
```

The regex is similar to before, but only digits are retained now. This also prevents the need for a second `str.replace` call.

Comment: Identifying `,` in that regex was a huge task haha. Regex usually wins everytime

Comment: @Bharathshetty Yes but I'm loathe to chain two replace calls. :-(

Comment: If you can trust that there are always two decimal places, you can skip worrying about `.` or `,` and just keep `\d` then convert to `float` or `int` and divide by `100`

Comment: @piRSquared Yes, and once again I appreciate the fact that you offered an improvement over writing an answer, just for that change. Though if you had, I'd have upvoted it.

Comment: I often write answers with completely different concepts to existing answers while leaving feedback on improving said existing answers.

Comment: Hallo, thanks for your comments. I already have a solution using `replace`, but I am looking into how this can be done using LOCALE, except possibly replacing `€` with empty space. I am new to Python, but in SAS we have something called informats and by specifying German/US format one can do it directly. My dataset is big, so `replace` function just slows down the process and that was my reason for looking into LOCALE. Thank you so much for your inputs.

Comment: @OliverS I'm not a codec expert. This answer works, but if you refuse it just because it doesn't use "LOCALE"s, then I can't help you.

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure pandas even supports that.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, your comments are always appreciated and have learnt a lot from your posts on this website. No doubt the answer works and mine works as well, but both too slow, when I compare it witht he speed with with SAS does this. That's why I thought to investigate how LOCALES can expedite this.

Comment: @OliverS It's not that I don't want to help you... I just don't know how :-)

Comment: @COLDSPEED well if PANDAS has not implemented it, then this entire exercise comes to a naught and I have to be content with `replace` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155496/discussion-between-oliver-s-and-cs).

Comment: @COLDSPEED: what if we have empty values in the column Revenue: `df['Revenue'].str.replace('[^\d,]', '').str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)`. In this case `astype(float)` will give a `ValueError: Could not convert string to float`. One can circumvent this problem by writing a function with try/except and polulating empty nalues with `NaN` and applying this with `lambda/apply`. But is there an implicit functionality in `astype` so as to preclude this problem with missing values?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I could solve this issue by using pd.to_numeric() instead and it implicitly converted missing values to naN. Thank you in anticipation :)

Answer (score 2):

Without use of `regex` and using comprehensions

```
df.assign(
    Revenue=[int(i.replace('.', '')) + float(j) / 100
             for i, j in (x.split()[0].split(',')
             for x in df.Revenue.values.tolist())]
)

           Revenue
0         23979.12
1       7993137.63
2           418.83
```

---

This borders on ridiculous

```
pd.read_csv(
    pd.io.common.StringIO(
        df[['Revenue']].to_csv(index=None, sep='|')
    ), decimal=',', thousands='.', delim_whitespace=True, usecols=[0])

      Revenue
0    23979.12
1  7993137.63
2      418.83
```

Comment: Any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465641/is-there-a-way-to-convert-revenue-figues-in-german-european-format-to-american-f/46465704?noredirect=1#comment79887505_46465704

Comment: @piRSquared Many thanks Pi for trying to help. Highly appreciated :)

Comment: I am trying (-:

Comment: @OliverS you may want to see if you can get MaxU to answer this.  He might know.

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = ["123,456.34","245.323.323,23","342,323.3"]
EU_format = re.compile("\\.[0-9]*,")
for val in nums:
    if EU_format.search(val):
        print("EU number -", val)
        val = re.sub("[^0-9\,]", "", val).replace(",",".")
        before,after = val.split(".")[0],val.split(".")[1]
        before = re.sub(r'(\d\d\d)(?=\d)',r'\1,',before[::-1])[::-1]
        final = ".".join([before,after])
        print("Converted to US - ",final)
    else:
        print("US Number -", val)
```

Output -

```
US Number - 123,456.34
EU number - 245.323.323,23
Converted to US -  245,323,323.23
US Number - 342,323.3
```